# uitableview cell data not updating from new values in firebase

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

I have a loader function which populates my UITableView with expandable sections: [image]

which works fine. the number (n / total) is the number completed out of the total. with an observer function listening to firebase, i can update these values accordingly, and have tested and confirmed this works.

```
// real time updates for numCompleted/totalNum per category
func observeUserProgress() {
    let userProgress = Database.database().reference().child("userProgress").child(currentUserUID!)
    userProgress.observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) -> Void in
        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let sectionKey = child.key
            let objStatuses = child.value as! [String:Int]
            self.sections.filter{$0.id==sectionKey}.first?.numCompleted = objStatuses.filter{$0.value == 1}.count
            self.sections.filter{$0.id==sectionKey}.first?.totalNumber = objStatuses.count
            for key in objStatuses.keys {
                Database.fetchObjectiveStatus(userId: self.currentUserUID!, categoryId: sectionKey, objectiveId: key) {
                    (status) in
                    self.sections.filter{$0.id==sectionKey}.first?.objectives.filter{$0.id==key}.first?.completed = status
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } )
}
```

`self.sections.filter{$0.id==sectionKey}.first?.numCompleted = objStatuses.filter{$0.value == 1}.count`
and
`self.sections.filter{$0.id==sectionKey}.first?.totalNumber = objStatuses.count`

update my in memory `sections` object, which is an array of categories to facilitate the nesting of rows underneath their respective section headers.

`self.tableView.reloadData()` triggers when the data is changed and i can see the number increase if a user completes an objective (i trigger this from firebase console directly editing the status).

the status correctly updates in my in memory structure, however, the cell is not updating and keeps referencing its original value. I can tell this by my `debugPrint()` statements.

In my `cellForRowAt` function:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let objective:Objective = sections[indexPath.section - 1].objectives[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "objectiveTableCell") as! ObjectiveCustomTableViewCell
    let title = objective.title
    let imgUrl = objective.overlayImgUrl ?? ""
    let objectiveDescription =  objective.description
    let pointsValue = String(describing: objective.pointsValue)
    let objectiveId =  objective.id
    let status = objective.completed
    debugPrint("yes: \(status)")
    cell.initializeObjectives(title: title, detail: objectiveDescription, pointsValue: pointsValue , overlayImgURL: imgUrl , objectiveID: objectiveId, status: status)
    return cell
}
```

and my custom cell class:

```
class ObjectiveCustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var objectiveTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var objectiveDetailText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pointsValue: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var objectiveStatusImageView: UIImageView!

    var overlayImgUrl:String = ""
    var objectiveID:String = ""
    var status:Int = 0

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        switch status {
        case 1:
            self.objectiveStatusImageView.image = UIImage(named: "check")
        case -1:
            self.objectiveStatusImageView.image = UIImage(named: "me")
        default:
            debugPrint(status)
            self.objectiveStatusImageView.image = UIImage(named: "me")
        }
    
    }


    func initializeObjectives(title:String, detail:String, pointsValue:String, overlayImgURL:String, objectiveID:String, status:Int) {
        self.status = status
        objectiveTitle.text = title
        objectiveDetailText.text = detail
        self.pointsValue.text = pointsValue
        self.overlayImgUrl = overlayImgURL
        self.objectiveID = objectiveID
    }

}
```

the print statements with `yes: status` always show the correct status, but the simple status print from the custom cell class always shows zero. the other weird part is that the status does not print at all when reloading data, only when the tableview first appears in the view. if i edit data in firebase to change a status to 1, i get the "yes: 1" in my console but i do not see '1' coming from the cell awakeFromNib function.

how do I reinitialize the nib when the status of a cell changes?

### EDIT

I have defined sections as an array of `<ObjectiveCategory>`:

`var sections = [ObjectiveCategory]()`

and I have defined ObjectiveCategory here:

```
class ObjectiveCategory {
    lazy var title: String = ""
    lazy var objectives = [Objective]()
    var collapsed: Bool
    var numCompleted = 0
    lazy var totalNumber = 0
    var id:String = ""

    init(collapsed: Bool = false) {
        self.collapsed = collapsed
    }
}
```

`Objective` is just a class that is initialized to make parsing the JSON easier. ObjectiveCategory is used to make the sections in my tableview.

I solved this by simply calling `self.awakeFromNib()` after setting the local properties in the function `cell.initializeObjectives()`. I guess the issue is just that `awakeFromNib()` is called before my own initializer function. Wondering if there is a better way to do this. In 2.0 of this application I plan on moving entirely to auto-layout and eliminating .XIB files entirely, so I suppose I will rely on the appropriate life cycle method(s) in the near future.

my hack:

```
func initializeObjectives(title:String, detail:String, pointsValue:String, overlayImgURL:String, objectiveID:String, status:Int) {
    self.status = status
    objectiveTitle.text = title
    objectiveDetailText.text = detail
    self.pointsValue.text = pointsValue
    self.overlayImgUrl = overlayImgURL
    self.objectiveID = objectiveID
    self.awakeFromNib()
}
```

Comment: can you show us how you define `sections` variable?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48690711/objects-viewing-uicollectionview/48690808#48690808